# Dynamic Image Control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a image control dynamically in vb.net. On declaration of `new image(dim img as New Image()` it shows the following error:

> Error: New cannot be used in a class that is MustInherit

Is there any solution? This is where I need to use it:

```
Dim imgBox As New Image()
imgBox.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" & strImgName
Dim tr As New TableRow
Dim tdRight As New TableCell
Dim tdLeft As New TableCell
tdRight.Controls.Add(imgBox)
tdLeft.Controls.Add(imgBox)
tr.Controls.Add(tdLeft)   'adding left cell
tr.Controls.Add(tdRight)  'adding right cell
tb.Controls.Add(tr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are getting the `Image` class in the `System.Drawing` namespace, as that class is abstract. If you have included the `System.Drawing` namespace, you have to specify where the `Image` class that you want to use is.

For example:

```
Dim imgBox As New System.Windows.Controls.Image()
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa It worked with   Dim imgBox As New WebControls.Image()